# Web Page won't adjust to browser window size

Tags: html, css, layout

I'm making a website from scratch and all I currently have is the NAV bar. But I figured I'd get this problem solved before I continue on with development. Anytime I minimise the browser, my nav bar will not stay in a straight line. I've included the code below. The text editor I use is Brackets, I've tried multiple things for the past week but nothing has worked.

```css
//CSS
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: beige;
  font-family: 'Work Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.container {
  width: 86.5%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.header {
  background-color: grey;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0px;
  position: fixed;
}

.header::after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.logo {
  float: left;
  padding: 0.5%;
}

nav {
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
}

nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 99px;
  padding-top: 25px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
//HTML
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>

  <link href="MPstyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>M/P</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="header">
    <div class="container">
      <img src="logo.png" alt="logo" class="logo" width="50" height="50">
      <nav>
        <ul>

          <li> <a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li> <a href="#">About</a></li>
          <li> <a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
          <li> <a href="#">Contact</a></li>

        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably looking for something like this.

When I'm stuck with a layout and I cannot get it right, I start by adding borders to each element. This way you see how each element is spaced on the page and based on that I start to tweak CSS properties to place items in its place. Obviously, the more you work with CSS the easier it gets. Once I'm happy with the layout I then remove the borders.

Adjustments I've made:

1. Made the header full width so it covers the entire width of the page
2. Gave the logo 20% width of the page.
3. The remaining space 80% is taken up by the menu
4. Then each list-item is allowed to take up 20%.

If you resize the page, you'll see that by using percentages it will assign space properly. I hope this helps you along and good luck with the rest of the page.

```css
//CSS
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: beige;
  font-family: 'Work Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.header {
  background-color: grey;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0px;
  position: fixed;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.logo {
  float: left;
  width: 19%;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

nav {
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  width: 80%;
    border: 1px solid yellow;
}

nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

nav li {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20%;
  margin: 1rem 0;
     border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
//HTML
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>

  <link href="MPstyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>M/P</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="header">
    <div class="container">
      <img src="logo.png" alt="logo" class="logo" width="50" height="50">
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li> <a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li> <a href="#">About</a></li>
          <li> <a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
          <li> <a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Hi Asa, here's a [helpful site](https://www.freecodecamp.org) that I used myself to get better in CSS. In their Basic CSS section they'll guide you through doing various small tasks so you learn as you build things.

Comment: Awesome, I'm glad that worked out. Don't forget to mark the answer as accepted. This will help other people to know we came to a solution.